# How would I make a dialog look different in a C# Windows program like those in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, winforms, styles

Visual Studio 2010 has a completely different visual style on the child dialogs, the ones that you can move around and re-size within the program.

How would I create and implement custom styles for dialogs and controls in my own programs? Do I need to manually redraw them or is there some easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a bit of FYI:

Visual studio 2010 is written in WPF: [Blog regarding VS2010 and how it's built](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/16/wpf-in-visual-studio-2010-part-1.aspx)
This pretty much means they had full control over the full look and feel of the IDE.  There are lots of control packs that give you a similar look and feel and ability, from various companies, and indeed some free ones too.

I'd look on [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/) for things related to WPF (controls, etc) and additionally, there are the commercial sites such as [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/overview.aspx).  There are plenty of other commercial ones too, just Google for them and you should find a good amount.  I hope that helps point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Form.FormBorderStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx) to set the style of the window border/header.

Set `yourForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;` if you want the tool window style.

If you need the docking support too you might want to use a library like [DockPanel Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/).